# How do I get the height of the page after an ajax load?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I setting one of 2 elements to be whichever is the greatest height.  I'm checking the height of window, sidebar and #primary container and making sure whichever is the greatest is the height all elements i set to.  However, on this page, on interaction with a select button, there is an ajax load.  My page height then increases.  I expected the new height to be picked up by my function, but it still returns the old height pre-ajax load.

My code is below:

```
//on change of the select button load ajax content, then run changeSidebarHeight()
$('#choose-pathway').change(function() {
        var url=$(this).val();
        $('#ajax-pathway-container').load(url + ' #pathway',changeSidebarHeight);
});


function changeSidebarHeight(){
        var primaryHeight=$('#primary').height();
        var sidebarHeight=$('#sidebar').height();
        var windowHeight=$(window).height();    
            //this always returns the same value, before the ajax load and after, despite the page being about 600 pixels taller
            console.log($('html').height());        
        if(primaryHeight > sidebarHeight){
             $('#sidebar').height(primaryHeight );

        }else{
              $('#sidebar').height(windowHeight );
              $('#primary').height(windowHeight);
        }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure your `html` element is actually as tall as the page?

Comment: no its not when I inspect it in chrome it only highlights to the height of the page before inserting the ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use $(document).height(); but keep in mind that with no doctype tag to your page chome reports the same value for both calls ($(window) and $(document)).
Adding a strict doctype causes the values to work as advertised.
But you can also use $(body).height();

Comment: ahh it does!  I thought HTML was the highest up the DOM

Comment: does document.height give the height of the whole page then rather than just the height of the browser window (which I assume is what window.height does)?

Comment: Yes it gives the all document height and not only the view port height

Answer (score 1):

Please try  `$(document).height();` code for getting the height of the window.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using $(window) or $(document) instead of $(html)